# What breaks using nWoD rules with classic WoD cosmology?

Tags: world-of-darkness, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, cosmology

What major problems will I run into if I ran an nWoD game with the classic WoD cosmology being the "true" cosmology?  At this point, my major (only) concerns are the big three (Werewolf, Mage and Vampire).

Specifically, I'd like to keep the Werewolf triumvirate and the Mage cosmology as well as the classic Umbra.  Having said this, I'm not married to the automatic Werewolf - Vampire enmity, I'd maybe downplay it to the usual fantasy Elf-Dwarf racial relationship.  As for Vampires, I am honestly not sure what I want the real cosmology to be.

I'm willing to try a mixed supernatural game if my players want to and at least one of them wants to be a vampire, but that is my least preferred of the three.  I believe that as of now it is the player that wants to be a vampire that has classic WoD experience which was almost exclusively VtM.

I have experience with classic WoD and am reading through nWoD currently.  I like that more than just werewolves have multiple chargen choices to determine their characters' origin, though I suppose this will be somewhat problematic for mages if I ditch the Atlantis thing but keep the paths and orders of nWoD and the old cosmology.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on which cosmologies you're hoping to keep? Caine, son of Adam, as progenitor of vampires will have a different impact than "The Triatic Powers are real and run things" or "the nature of reality bends with paradigm and will."

Comment: This is really a side note, but I have always had trouble incorporating mages into a game with vampires and werewolves.  Vampires and werewolves play relatively well together, but mages break a lot of assumptions, especially after some experience has been built up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you choose to keep the Masquerade cosmology in Requiem, you'll need to address the issue of Generation. In Masquerade, your distance from Caine (and, thus, your social standing and maximal level of vampire power) is fixed at the Embrace, barring diablerie. This sets the stage for some of the big conflicts, like elders vs. neonates and sects vs. anarchs. In Requiem, Blood Potency does rise over time, you can spend XP to raise it, and in some circumstances even decreases. Figuring out how this interacts with Masquerade's structure will be important.

If you choose to use the cosmology of Apocalypse in Forsaken, you'll need to address the fact that the ethics and ideals espoused by the Garou are better exemplified by the Pure than by the Uratha, and that spirits are in emnity with you, rather than allies against a greater foe. Not a big Werewolf fan, so that's what I've got there.

If you choose to use the cosmology of Ascension in Awakening, you'll need to figure out what paradigm and paradox mean in a world that doesn't run on consensual reality. It sounds like you just want to use Awakening's mechanics in an Ascension game, rather than bring the cosmology over, so the Translation Guides promoted by @Flamma are probably your best bet. Otherwise, just hang out until Second Edition, which should make such matters clearer.

Comment: Do you have any evidence second edition won't make things worse?
I expect it will be futher from owod.

Comment: @Oxinabox: Yes, but *explicitly* so. Some of the difficulty in mixing cosmologies is expecting old words to mean the same things they once did. Awakening 2E is going to have explicit ways of handling rotes, magical styles, legacies and the like that will give more structure. (Evidence is based on the material being posted by the developer at the OPP web page.)

Answer (score 10):

I think the only problem you can find is that you may lack of mechanics to specific setting elements. For instance, you have Ventrue in both books, but AFAIK you don't have Tremere in NWOD. There are many bloodlines that exist in both settings, but are too different. Another examples would be Paths of Enlightenment or Thaumaturgy Paths (I think).

Mage: The Ascension and Mage: The Awakening have a different set of spheres. Euthanatoi are specialist in the Entropy Sphere, which doesn't exist in Mage: The Awakening. Also, there are nine traditions beacause there are nine spheres. If you think that's important on the setting, you should make a new tradition, which isn't easy.

Fortunately, a lot of the work is already done. White Wolf published the translation guides, which tells you how to translate elements from one game to another.

- [Vampire Translation Guide.](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/86202/Vampire-Translation-Guide)
- [Werewolf Translation Guide](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/100710/Werewolf-Translation-Guide).
- [Mage Translation Guide](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/114433/Mage-Translation-Guide).

Answer (score 4):

Even with the translation guides, WoD players are a mixed bag of personalities. This, aside from rules hiccups, will be a massive hurdle.

Why? People will potentially argue the rules. Part of a game is the rules, part is setting, part of it is how people interpret it. It's that difference in interpretation that could cause the break.

I've run both types of games and I've run into a large number of personalities types. Regardless of the system version, have patience with them. :)

When nWoD came about there were a fairly large number of people who HATED it even before it was released. There are still oWoD fans who, though they have tried the new system, don't like it for various reasons.

So I would suggest polling your players, and getting a feel for what they like and don't like. If you have either nWoD or oWoD players in your group, ask them their thoughts and tell them flat out what you are attempting to do.

Being open with your communication, especially when trying to Hybridize, or adjust a game system or setting that is already well known, helps reduce tension and arguments ahead of time.

Also do your research, as much of it as you can.

Lastly - the Storyteller system is FLEXIBLE. Some folks forget this and that can cause strife within a game. Yes, the rules are in place to enforce a certain level of fairness. However, even the creators of the system stated in their book lines - if something isn't working try something else (paraphrased).

On the flip side of that, some people don't like games that are too "free-form" and feel more comfortable and secure knowing there are things they can expect if x or y happens. Not having that security can loose the players' trust rather quickly, and potentially start arguments.

Knowing your players, knowing what type they are, and knowing what type of GM-ing they prefer does go a long way making a game more comfortable for the whole.

As Flamma noted, a lot of the work has already been done. Just be aware there might be personality and ideology conflicts as well that you will face.